# Configure Nagios for email alerts in a windows domain

Tags: email, ubuntu, exchange-2007, nagios, exim

I have a Lucid Ubuntu Server running in a EBS 2008 windows domain. This server is running Nagios and I would like it to send email notifications to the Exchange 2007 server. I have installed *mailutils* and run a *dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config* however I still don't have it setup correctly.

I have been trying to send an email via command line first as a proof of concept for the Nagios command but the exim4 log file says:

```
2010-09-23 11:29:32 Start queue run: pid=8248
2010-09-23 11:29:53 1OySgu-0002xV-5N internet.domain.com.au [**my external IP**] Connection timed out
2010-09-23 11:29:53 1OySgu-0002xV-5N == hsee@domain.com.au R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out
2010-09-23 11:29:53 End queue run: pid=8248
2010-09-23 11:59:32 Start queue run: pid=9958
2010-09-23 11:59:32 1OySgu-0002xV-5N == hsee@domain.com.au R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host
```

I can telnet into the exchange server via 25 with the exchange machine IP.

I would like it configured correctly for just a simple internal network direct send to my exchange server. From looking at the log it seems like it wants to go out onto the Internet first instead of staying internal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your exim4 installation as a smarthost setup. This can be done by re-running dpkg-reconfigure and selecting the correct option. Then enter the name (or IP address) of your Exchange Server as the smarthost.

Make sure that the smarthost actually has an account (or a contact) set up for the email address you want to use. You may also have to do something about authentication (depends on  your Exchange server configuration).

Comment: Yep spot on. After a bit more looking at docco and exim config files I needed to have a smarthost scenario setup. The dc_smarthost var now contains my SMTP. Thanks for posting!